# How to find out if an upsert was an update with PostgreSQL 9.5+ UPSERT?

Tags: postgresql, upsert, postgresql-9.5

Writable CTEs were considered a solution to UPSERT prior to 9.5 as described in [Insert, on duplicate update in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109061/insert-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql/8702291#8702291)

It is possible to perform an UPSERT with the information whether it ended up as an UPDATE or an INSERT with the following Writable CTEs idiom:

```
WITH
    update_cte AS (
        UPDATE t SET v = $1 WHERE id = $2 RETURNING 'updated'::text status
    ),
    insert_cte AS (
        INSERT INTO t(id, v) SELECT $2, $1 WHERE NOT EXISTS
            (SELECT 1 FROM update_cte) RETURNING 'inserted'::text status
    )
 (SELECT status FROM update_cte) UNION (SELECT status FROM insert_cte)
```

This query will return either "updated" or "inserted", or may (rarely) fail with a constraint violation in as described in https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/78510/why-is-cte-open-to-lost-updates

Can something similar be achieved using PostgreSQL 9.5+ new "UPSERT" syntax, benefiting from its optimization and avoiding the possible constraint violation?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I believe `xmax::text::int > 0` would be the easiest trick:

```
so=# DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tab;
NOTICE:  table "tab" does not exist, skipping
DROP TABLE
so=# CREATE TABLE tab(id INT PRIMARY KEY, col text);
CREATE TABLE
so=# INSERT INTO tab(id, col) VALUES (1,'a');
INSERT 0 2
so=# INSERT INTO tab(id, col)
VALUES (3, 'c'), (4, 'd'), (1,'aaaa')
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET col = EXCLUDED.col
returning *,case when xmax::text::int > 0 then 'updated' else 'inserted' end,ctid;
 id | col  |   case   | ctid
----+------+----------+-------
  3 | c    | inserted | (0,3)
  4 | d    | inserted | (0,4)
  1 | aaaa | updated  | (0,5)
(3 rows)

INSERT 0 3
so=# INSERT INTO tab(id, col)
VALUES (3, 'c'), (4, 'd'), (1,'aaaa')
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET col = EXCLUDED.col
returning *,case when xmax::text::int > 0 then 'updated' else 'inserted' end,ctid;
 id | col  |  case   | ctid
----+------+---------+-------
  3 | c    | updated | (0,6)
  4 | d    | updated | (0,7)
  1 | aaaa | updated | (0,8)
(3 rows)

INSERT 0 3
```

Comment: You could just use:

```
RETURNING (xmax = 0) AS inserted
```

Comment: Is there any way to find out which rows were not affected because of `DO NOTHING` clause?

Answer (score 10):

Drawing from [@lad2025's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34764448/2617867), the result can be achieved by abusing [settings](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set.html) and [customized options](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-custom.html) with [related functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html) in WHERE clauses to get a required side-effect.

```
CREATE TABLE t(id INT PRIMARY KEY, v TEXT);

INSERT INTO t (id, v)
    SELECT $1, $2
    WHERE 'inserted' = set_config('upsert.action', 'inserted', true)
    ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE
        SET v = EXCLUDED.v
        WHERE 'updated' = set_config('upsert.action', 'updated', true)
RETURNING current_setting('upsert.action') AS "upsert.action";
```

The third parameter of `set_config` is `is_local`: `true` means the setting will go away at the end of transaction. More precisely, `current_setting('upsert.action')` will return NULL (and not throw an error) until the end of the session.

Comment: Oh my, that's ugly! It makes my vision blur. I definitely do not want to remember this, let alone apply it!~

Comment: you can do it with `xmax::text::int > 0` - without transaction level setting (which is indeed original hack)

Comment: @VaoTsun is right. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38858662/454126 for an example of how to use `xmax` for this purpose. Not pretty, but definitely prettier than `set_config` / `current_setting`.

Answer (score 7):

In `SQL Server` `MERGE`  statement has `$action` that returns string `'INSERT', 'UPDATE', or 'DELETE'`.

For `Postgresql` I can't find function/variable that does similiar thing for `RETURNING`.

One way to workaround it is to add column `is_updated` to your table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tab;

CREATE TABLE tab(id INT PRIMARY KEY, col VARCHAR(100),
                 is_updated BOOLEAN DEFAULT false);
INSERT INTO tab(id, col) VALUES (1,'a'), (2, 'b');


-- main query
INSERT INTO tab(id, col)
VALUES (3, 'c'), (4, 'd'), (1,'aaaa')
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET col = EXCLUDED.col, is_updated = true
RETURNING id,col,
          CASE WHEN is_updated THEN 'UPDATED' ELSE 'INSERTED' END AS action;
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/CSD68513)**

Output:

```
╔════╦══════╦══════════╗
║ id ║ col  ║  action  ║
╠════╬══════╬══════════╣
║  3 ║ c    ║ INSERTED ║
║  4 ║ d    ║ INSERTED ║
║  1 ║ aaaa ║ UPDATED  ║
╚════╩══════╩══════════╝
```

Comment: Where is VALUES (2, 'b') in the output?

Comment: @kometen There is no need for it. It exists before. Why do you want to return entire table? Only records that are inserted/updated

Comment: But (2, 'b') is also inserted. And is_updated defaults to false. So I figured it would show up as INSERTED.

Comment: @kometen The point is this: imagine you have table with 2 milions records. Now you execute the main query. The returning will give back only 3 records (2 inserted, 1 updated). The first insert is to prepopulate data (for demo).

Comment: OK, so it's is relative to that particular INSERT. Very useful, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

`(xmax::text::bigint > 0)` or `(NOT xmax = 0)`. Typecast to integer will break once transaction count will reach the integer overflow.

Comment: How likely is this to happen?

Comment: It depends on your transactions volume. It happened for us on a database that was running for years with multiple transactions per second.