# Differentiate inserted and updated rows in UPSERT using system columns

Tags: postgresql, upsert, postgresql-9.5

Several questions have been asked recently here on SO about how to differentiate inserted and updated rows in a PostgreSQL UPSERT  statement (`INSERT ... ON CONFLICT ... DO UPDATE ...`).

Here is a simple example:

```
create table t(i int primary key, x int);
insert into t values(1,1);
insert into t values(1,11),(2,22)
    on conflict(i) do update set x = excluded.i*11
    returning *, xmin, xmax;

╔═══╤════╤══════╤══════╗
║ i │ x  │ xmin │ xmax ║
╠═══╪════╪══════╪══════╣
║ 1 │ 11 │ 7696 │ 7696 ║
║ 2 │ 22 │ 7696 │    0 ║
╚═══╧════╧══════╧══════╝
```

So:

- `xmax > 0` (or `xmax = xmin`) → row was updated
- `xmax = 0` → row was inserted

IMO, it is not too clear from the [explanation in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-system-columns.html).

Is it possible to base the logic on those columns? Is there more significant explanation about system columns (except the source code)?

And are my assumptions correct??

Comment: Why not create another column for your metadata that you set during your update?

Comment: @vol7ron Because it is slowing down the whole query. I am feeling that the existing columns (including the system columns) is enough.

Comment: Interesting. My intuition says it should work, however it is undocumented behaviour and there is no guarantee that this won't change someday. I wouldn't rather use this in a professional project.

Comment: @klin My Intuition agrees with your Intuition. Actually it is an obvious task for such queries. Looking to the speed of the PostgreSQL development...

Comment: It might be worthwhile to convince Postgres developers to formalize (document) this issue.

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't recommend relying on the old tuple's xmax, though it'll work with the current implementation. I think we should probably have a keyword or pseudofunction to use to request the insert vs update decision. Post to pgsql-hackers to point this out please.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

I think that this is an interesting question that deserves an in-depth answer; please bear with me if it is a little bit lengthy.

In short: Your guess is right, and you can use the following `RETURNING` clause to determine if the row was inserted and not updated:

```
RETURNING (xmax = 0) AS inserted
```

Now the detailed explanation:

When a row is updated, PostgreSQL does not modify the data, but creates a *new version* of the row; the old version will be deleted by *autovacuum* when it is no longer needed. A version of a row is called a *tuple*, so in PostgreSQL there can be more than one tuples per row.

`xmax` serves two different purposes:

1. As stated in the documentation, it can be the transaction ID of the transaction that deleted (or updated) the tuple (“tuple” is another word for “row”). Only transactions with a transaction ID between `xmin` and `xmax` can see the tuple. An old tuple can be deleted safely if there is no transaction with a transaction ID less than `xmax`.
2. `xmax` is also used to store *row locks*. In PostgreSQL, row locks are not stored in the lock table, but in the tuple to avoid overflow of the lock table.
   If only one transaction has a lock on the row, `xmax` will contain the transaction ID of the locking transaction. If more than one transaction has a lock on the row, `xmax` contains the number of a so-called *multixact*, which is a data structure that in turn contains the transaction IDs of the locking transactions.

The documentation of `xmax` is not complete, because the exact meaning of this field is considered an implementation detail and cannot be understood without knowing `t_infomask` of the tuple, which is not immediately visible via SQL.

You can install the contrib module `pageinspect` to view this and other fields of a tuple.

I ran your example, and this is what I see when I use the `heap_page_items` function to examine details (the transaction ID numbers are of course different in my case):

```
SELECT *, ctid, xmin, xmax FROM t;

┌───┬────┬───────┬────────┬────────┐
│ i │ x  │ ctid  │  xmin  │  xmax  │
├───┼────┼───────┼────────┼────────┤
│ 1 │ 11 │ (0,2) │ 102508 │ 102508 │
│ 2 │ 22 │ (0,3) │ 102508 │      0 │
└───┴────┴───────┴────────┴────────┘
(2 rows)

SELECT lp, lp_off, t_xmin, t_xmax, t_ctid,
       to_hex(t_infomask) AS t_infomask, to_hex(t_infomask2) AS t_infomask2
FROM heap_page_items(get_raw_page('laurenz.t', 0));

┌────┬────────┬────────┬────────┬────────┬────────────┬─────────────┐
│ lp │ lp_off │ t_xmin │ t_xmax │ t_ctid │ t_infomask │ t_infomask2 │
├────┼────────┼────────┼────────┼────────┼────────────┼─────────────┤
│  1 │   8160 │ 102507 │ 102508 │ (0,2)  │ 500        │ 4002        │
│  2 │   8128 │ 102508 │ 102508 │ (0,2)  │ 2190       │ 8002        │
│  3 │   8096 │ 102508 │      0 │ (0,3)  │ 900        │ 2           │
└────┴────────┴────────┴────────┴────────┴────────────┴─────────────┘
(3 rows)
```

The meanings of `t_infomask` and `t_infomask2` can be found in `src/include/access/htup_details.h`. `lp_off` is the offset of the tuple data in the page, and `t_ctid` is the *current tuple ID* which consists of the page number and a tuple number within the page. Since the table was newly created, all data are in page 0.

Let me discuss the three rows returned by `heap_page_items`.

1. At *line pointer* (`lp`) 1 we find the old, updated tuple. It originally had `ctid = (0,1)`, but that got modified to contain the tuple ID of the current version during update. The Tuple was created by transaction 102507 and invalidated by transaction 102508 (the transaction that issued the `INSERT  ... ON CONFLICT`). This tuple is not visible any more an will get removed during `VACUUM`.

   `t_infomask` shows that both `xmin` and `xmax` belong to committed transactions and consequently show when the tuples was created and deleted. `t_infomask2` shows that the tuple was updated with a HOT (*heap only tuple*) update, which means that the updated tuple is in the same page as the original tuple and no indexed column was modified (see `src/backend/access/heap/README.HOT`).
2. At line pointer 2 we see the new, updated tuple that was created by transaction the `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT` (transaction 102508).

   `t_infomask` shows that this tuple is the result of an update, `xmin` is valid, and `xmax` contains a `KEY SHARE` row lock (which is no longer relevant since the transaction has completed). This row lock was taken during `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT` processing. `t_infomask2` shows that this is a HOT tuple.
3. At line pointer 3 we see the newly inserted row.

   `t_infomask` shows that `xmin` is valid and `xmax` is invalid. `xmax` is set to 0 because this value is always used for newly inserted tuples.

So the nonzero `xmax` of the updated row is an implementation artifact caused by a row lock. It is conceivable that `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT` is reimplemented one day so that this behaviour changes, but I think that is unlikely.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation about the system columns. It is really useful to understand how it works internally.

Comment: This is an excellent and interesting answer that deserves more upvotes.

Comment: Does that mean we can rely on this behaviour? Cause this might also change if Postgres for some reason decided to not implement update in terms of delete.

Comment: It is not documented and a side effect of the implementation, so it could change. But the odds are not very high.

Comment: Can you explain, how do you understand what t_infomask show?

Comment: @yuoggy It is documented in the PostgreSQL source file `src/include/access/htup_details.h`.