# Why xmin and xmax values are same in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, mvcc

I've been learning MVCC in PostgreSQL. As I understood, when the row is updated, a new row will be added and the `xmax` value in old row will have the value of the `xmin` of the newly added row.
When I checked it in the table I have in my Postgres DB, the `xmin` and `xmax` values are the same. What does it mean?

```
   xmin   |   xmax   |    id    |     serial     | paid 
----------+----------+----------+----------------+------
 54569114 | 54569114 | 11099324 | 76605297311437 | t
 54569111 | 54569111 | 11099323 | 38131108141783 | t
 54569101 | 54569101 | 11099322 | 49399633274146 | t
 54569092 |        0 | 11099321 | 44672543705101 | f
 54569090 | 54569090 | 11099320 | 21324499293647 | t
 54569083 |        0 | 11099319 | 82878160317074 | f
 54569079 | 54569079 | 11099318 | 31091666079121 | t
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`xmax` does double duty: it is used to mark visibility (together with `xmin`, but it is also used to hold [row locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-ROWS).

To disambiguate between these two uses the status of the transaction and further “invisible” flags in the tuple are used.

So if you see a row where the two values are identical, the transaction that created the row also locked the row. This is normally a sign that the tuple was created with `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT`.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39058213/6464308) and [my blog post](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/whats-in-an-xmax/) for more information.

Comment: Some records have `0` value in `xmax`.  `xmax` values are becoming identical after updating a row. If you notice, paid is true on the rows where `xmin` and `xmax` are identical. Because this is invoice table, and when payment is made, invoice will got updated.

Comment: As I said, the transaction that created the row must have locked it. Try to find out the exact sequence of SQL statements, then you can understand how it happened.