# Transaction rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only - UnexpectedRollbackException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have this kind of code:

```
@Service
public class AService {


      public void methodA() {
           try {
               methodB();
            } catch (Exception e) {
               methodC(e);
            }
       }

 }
```

methodB is reading from DB.
methodC is writing the Exception if occurred to the DB.
for some reason, when method B throws an error, the writing in methodC is not working and I get - UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only.

would appreciate any advice on this, thanks!

Comment: Please add the code for `methodB()` and `methodC()`. Additionally, please include all relevant transaction related annotations. Thanks!

Comment: Try the solution on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354463/2933780)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a transaction managed by Spring (`@Transactional`) somewhere inside `methodB`. In Spring, a transaction is marked for rollback when a `RuntimeException` is thrown within this transaction.

From the Spring docs:

> In its default configuration, the Spring Framework’s transaction infrastructure code only marks a transaction for rollback in the case of runtime, unchecked exceptions; that is, when the thrown exception is an instance or subclass of RuntimeException.

See: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-rolling-back

Answer (score 0):

In case of an exception during DB access, Hibernate will [*generally*](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/7d30b57f15617f679a20aa1389c9385433e45b2c/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/internal/ExceptionConverterImpl.java#L312) mark the complete transaction as `rollbackOnly`, even if one would explicitly try to avoid this behavior via the `@Transactional(noRollbackFor=Exception.class)` annotation attribute.

So in these cases, there needs to be a different solution, such as having separate transactions for the two method calls.

(Similar problem: [handle sql exception for large data insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70341151/handle-sql-exception-for-large-data-insert/70371129#70371129))