# Update and Insert vs Upsert in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, database-performance, upsert

Say, I am building a camera app. Every time the user clicks a photo, the image is stored on the cloud. Because I want to restrict how many images are stored on the cloud, the app gets 10 URLs in an array called `listURLs` when it is initialised.

The first 10 clicks get `PUT` into the cloud, exhausting `listURLs`. Then, every time a click happens, a coin toss determines whether the latest click replaces an existing click on the cloud. Typical numbers would be 50 clicks, first 10 clicks get assigned a URL, and of the remaining 40 clicks, 20 of them overwrite an existing URL.

I store records of each app session in a Postgres DB. Each session will have an ID and **all** instances of clicks (which may or may not have a corresponding url). I also need to know the `url` corresponding to each click, if one exists. So, if there are 30 clicks, I will need to know which 10 of these have a corresponding `url`.

I can think of two ways of storing this data.

1. `tblClicksURLs` as a Table that has `click_id`, `url` and `url_active` as its fields. Every time a `click_id` and non-null `url` need to be inserted, update all other records with the same `url` to have `url_active` as `false`.
2. Two tables `tblClicks` and `tblURLs`. `tblURLs` has a `click_id` foreign key. Every time a `click_id` and non-null `url` need to be inserted, the `click_id` gets inserted into `tblClicks` and `click_id` and `url` get **upserted** into `tblURLs`. The upsert is based on whether the `url` already exists in `tblURLs`. So, for a given `url`, there will only be one `click_id` in `tblURLs`

So, in Case 1, I will have an `UPDATE` of `url_active` followed by  `INSERT` on the same table. In Case 2, I will have an `INSERT` into one table and an `UPSERT` into another. I will need indexing on `click_id`, but not on `url`.

If you are looking at writes of > 10k rows per second, maybe even more, **which of these two would be more efficient**? Assume that the numbers per session are similar to the one quoted above (50 clicks, etc.)

I could also register a `created_at` datetime for each record in Case 1, and just use the first non-null `url` ordered reverse-chronologically. But, I am trying to avoid this, unless the performance benefits are enormous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking about it for a while, I decided to use UPSERT along with a Unique Constraint on `tblClicksURLs`. The constraint is on `(url, url_active)`. Every time a new `(click_id, url, url_active)` record needs to be added, this record is UPSERT'ed. On conflict `url_active` is set to `null`. So, all records with this url will have their `url_active` set to `null`.

I then use

```
RETURNING (xmax = 0) AS inserted
```

as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39058213/postgresql-upsert-differentiate-inserted-and-updated-rows-using-system-columns-x) to check if the record was inserted or upserted. If the record was upserted, I update the `url_active` field of the latest record to `true`.

In this way, if a url is being inserted for the first time, it happens in a single transaction. If the url exists, it happens via two transactions.

Comment: If you are using `insert ... on conflict` to insert or update, then where does the second transaction come from?

Comment: It may be that I have understood/implemented this wrong, but, in my `insert ... on conflict`, I would update all the `url_active`'s to null. That is, I couldn't figure out how to update the existing records to null, and have the latest record as active. So, if `[(1, url_1, 1)]` was the initial state, the UPSERT of `(2, url_1, 1)` would update the table to `[(1, url_1, null), (2, url_1, null)]`. The second transaction would then update it to  `[(1, url_1, null), (2, url_1, 1)]`, which is the desired state.