# Postgresql Return Whether Upsert Query INSERTed a New Row or UPDATEd one

Tags: sql, postgresql, upsert, postgresql-9.5

I want to know if an upsert/"on conflict do update" query inserted a new row or only updated one.

There is a few ways that kind of work but they don't feel correct
Here is my current query:

```
INSERT INTO mytable
  (id, mycolumn)
VALUES
  (123, 'abc')
ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE
  SET mycolumn = 'xyz'
RETURNING (
    select max(id)
    from mytable
  ) = id as inserted
```

Answer (score 0):

This question came up on related and appears to be the correct answer
[Differentiate inserted and updated rows in UPSERT using system columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39058213/differentiate-inserted-and-updated-rows-in-upsert-using-system-columns)

```
RETURNING (xmax = 0) AS inserted
```