# What does this do in Postgresql: xmax::text::int > 0

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

What is the meaning and purpose of the following statement in Postgres:

```
xmax::text::int > 0
```

This looks like casting to text and then casting again to integer ???

Comment: That would appear to be what it is doing.  I would expect either `xmax > 0` or `xmax::int > 0` to be equivalent.

Comment: Sometimes you can't cast directly from one type to another (especially with custom types), so you have to first cast to text and then to the type you want.

Comment: `xmax::text::int` it is because `xmax` have type `xid` which can not be directly converted to `integer` value (look at [casts](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createcast.html) or somewhere) The meaning of this condition: `row was updated`. There is really great answer, with explanation, about the topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39204667/593144

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every table in Postgres has several [system columns.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-system-columns.html) They are non-standard, Postgres specific feature, which use requires basic knowledge about Postgres internals.

The column `xmax` essentially contains 0 or some transaction number. This value can not be however directly compared to numbers, because the column is of type `xid`, for which no corresponding operators have been defined. For this reason, it is necessary to use casting.

The comparison can be also written as

```
xmax::text <> '0'
```

The meaning of the expression can be inferred from the column description:

> xmax
>
> The identity (transaction ID) of the deleting transaction, or zero for an undeleted row version. It is possible for this column to be nonzero in a visible row version. That usually indicates that the deleting transaction hasn't committed yet, or that an attempted deletion was rolled back.

Comment: This explains the xmax::text but what is ::int for? Why double cast it instead just max::int <> '0'

Comment: @Jimski From the answer above: `This value can not be however directly compared to numbers, because the column is of type xid, for which no corresponding operators have been defined`. Anything (?) can be cast to text, hence the cast to text, then the cast to int.