# Check if Postgres query inserted or updated (via upsert)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm wondering if it's somehow possible to figure out if a postgres upsert query resulted in an insert or an update.

Something like this psuedocode:

```
insert into teammates (id, email, avatar, timezone)
values ($1, $2, $3, $4)
on conflict (id) do update set
  avatar = $3,
  timezone = $4
returning id, (updated = didUpdate);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find out if an upsert was an update with PostgreSQL 9.5+ UPSERT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34762732/how-to-find-out-if-an-upsert-was-an-update-with-postgresql-9-5-upsert)

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary to do a manual CTE upsert:

```
with u as (
    update teammates
    set (avatar, timezone) = ($3, $4)
    where id = $1
    returning id, true as updated
), i as (
    insert into teammates (id, email, avatar, timezone)
    select $1, $2, $3, $4
    where not exists (select 1 from u)
    returning id, false as updated
)
select id, updated from u
union all
select id, updated from i
```

Comment: That's the best answer I found among multiple similar questions. Because this answer doesn't require neither any additional `is_updated` / `update_timestamp` column nor does it use the `xmax` hack. Great!

Answer (score 0):

One way ti to manually check or performing a `SELECT` followed by `UPSERT` the below columns and see.

```
  avatar = $3,
  timezone = $4
```

You can as well have a `DATETIME` column named `LastModified` which should be updated on every `UPDATE` operation. It's then pretty straight forward for you to find out.